# How to check user is logged in or not with firebase for web App in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have authenticated into firebase for the futter Web App as well as mobile platform App.
but whenever rebuild or re-run the Web App it takes me to the login screen but I have implemented code for the user logged in or not but is not working.
it should navigate to home screen.

piece of Code:

```
class LandingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _LandingScreenState createState() => _LandingScreenState();
}

class _LandingScreenState extends State<LandingScreen> {
 bool isLoggedIn = false;
 FirebaseUser _user;
@override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
    if(user!=null){
      print("user:${user.uid}");
      setState(() {
        _user = user;
        isLoggedIn=true;
      });
     //  Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(
     //    builder: (context)=>HomeScreen(user: user)), (route) => false);
    }else{
      setState(() {
        isLoggedIn = false;
      });
       // Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(
       //  builder: (context)=>LoginScreen()), (route) => false);
    }
   });
 }
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
   return isLoggedIn?HomeScreen(user: _user):LoginScreen();
   
 }
}
```

Comment: re-run / hot-restart causes the application state to be reset. It is as good as uninstalling and re-installing an application. Only the hot-reload feature keeps state intact and performing hot-reload only updates the ui changes if any without affecting the application state.

Comment: How will I uninstall web application? please read my above statement

Comment: Sorry if my statements were confusing. I did not imply that you are uninstalling the web app. i tried to give an analogy between behaviors you are observing with respect to what happens when any flutter application is re-run or hot-restart is used. For a better explanation specifically in terms of web apps : consider you login to a website from a private/incognito browser and accidentally the browser closes. When you open the browser again the session information is lost as the local storage (application state) on the browser gets cleared. Re-running your web app clears the local state info.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing setState. SetState tells the widget to rebuild but InitState runs before the widget is built in the first place so it's not having an effect here. It might not fix the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((res) {
      print(res);
      if (res != null) {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home(user: res)),
        );
      }
      else
      {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()),
        );
      }
    });
  }
```

`currentUser()` is asynchronous therefore inside the `then()` navigate to the different pages according to the result

Comment: I have already tried this, it is okay with mobile platform app but not working for web application.

Comment: Did you debug it to check what is the issue in web?